# linq styling, chaining where clause vs and operator

Tags: linq, language-agnostic, coding-style

Is there a (logical/performance) difference to writing:

`ATable.Where(x=> condition1 && condition2 && condition3)`

or

`ATable.Where(x=>condition1).Where(x=>condition2).Where(x=>condition3)`

I've been using the former but realised that with the latter, I can read and copy parts of a query out to use somewhere else easier.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Short answer**
You should do what you feel is more readable and maintainable in your application as both will evaluate to the same collection.

**Long answer** *quite long*

**Linq To Objects**
`ATable.Where(x=> condition1 && condition2 && condition3)`
For this example Since there is only one predicate statement the compiler will only needs to generate one delegate and one compiler generated method.
*From reflector*

```
if (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate4 == null)
{
    CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate4 = new Func<ATable, bool>(null, (IntPtr) <Main>b__0);
}
Enumerable.Where<ATable>(tables, CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate4).ToList<ATable>();
```

The compiler generated method:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <Main>b__0(ATable m)
{
    return ((m.Prop1 && m.Prop2) && m.Prop3);
}
```

As you can see there is only one call into `Enumerable.Where<T>` with the delegate as expected since there was only one `Where` extension method.

`ATable.Where(x=>condition1).Where(x=>condition2).Where(x=>condition3)` now for this example a lot more code is generated.

```
    if (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate5 == null)
    {
        CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate5 = new Func<ATable, bool>(null, (IntPtr) <Main>b__1);
    }
    if (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate6 == null)
    {
        CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate6 = new Func<ATable, bool>(null, (IntPtr) <Main>b__2);
    }
    if (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate7 == null)
    {
        CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate7 = new Func<ATable, bool>(null, (IntPtr) <Main>b__3);
    }
    Enumerable.Where<ATable>(Enumerable.Where<ATable>(Enumerable.Where<ATable>(tables, CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate5), CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate6), CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate7).ToList<ATable>();
```

Since we have three chained Extension methods we also get three `Func<T>`s and also three compiler generated methods.

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <Main>b__1(ATable m)
{
    return m.Prop1;
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <Main>b__2(ATable m)
{
    return m.Prop2;
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <Main>b__3(ATable m)
{
    return m.Prop3;
}
```

Now this looks like this should be slower since heck there is a ton more code.  However since all execution is deferred until `GetEnumerator()` is called I doubt any noticeable difference will present itself.

*Some Gotchas that could effect performance*

- Any call to GetEnumerator in the chain will cause a the collection to be iterated. `ATable.Where().ToList().Where().ToList()` will result in an iteration of the collection with the first predicate when the `ToList` is called and then another iteration with the second `ToList`.  Try to keep the GetEnumerator called to the very last moment to reduce the number of times the collection is iterated.

**Linq To Entities**
Since we are using `IQueryable<T>` now our compiler generated code is a bit different as we are using `Expresssion<Func<T, bool>>` instead of our normal `Func<T, bool>`

Example in all in one.
`var allInOneWhere = entityFrameworkEntities.MovieSets.Where(m => m.Name == "The Matrix" && m.Id == 10 && m.GenreType_Value == 3);`

This generates one heck of a statement.

`IQueryable<MovieSet> allInOneWhere = Queryable.Where<MovieSet>(entityFrameworkEntities.MovieSets, Expression.Lambda<Func<MovieSet, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(CS$0$0000 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MovieSet), "m"), (MethodInfo) methodof(MovieSet.get_Name)), ..tons more stuff...ParameterExpression[] { CS$0$0000 }));`

The most notable is that we end up with one Expression tree that is parsed down to `Expression.AndAlso` pieces.  And also like expected we only have one call to `Queryable.Where`

`var chainedWhere = entityFrameworkEntities.MovieSets.Where(m => m.Name == "The Matrix").Where(m => m.Id == 10).Where(m => m.GenreType_Value == 3);`

I wont even bother pasting in the compiler code for this, way to long.  But in short we end up with Three calls to `Queryable.Where(Queryable.Where(Queryable.Where()))` and three expressions.  This again is expected as we have three chained `Where` clauses.

*Generated Sql*
Like `IEnumerable<T>` `IQueryable<T>` also does not execute until the enumerator is called.  Because of this we can be happy to know that both produce the same exact sql statement:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AtStore_Id] AS [AtStore_Id], 
[Extent1].[GenreType_Value] AS [GenreType_Value], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[MovieSet] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (N'The Matrix' = [Extent1].[Name]) AND (10 = [Extent1].[Id]) AND (3 = [Extent1].[GenreType_Value])
```

*Some Gotchas that could effect performance*

- Any call to GetEnumerator in the chain will cause a call out to sql, e.g. `ATable.Where().ToList().Where()` will actually query sql for all records matching the first predicate and then filter the list with linq to objects with the second predicate.
- Since you mention extracting the predicates to use else where, make **sure** they are in the form of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and not simply `Func<T, bool>`.  The first can be parsed to an expression tree and converted into valid sql, the second will trigger **ALL OBJECTS** returned and the `Func<T, bool>` will execute on that collection.

I hope this was a bit helpful to answer your question.