# Multiple filter LINQ search C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code which returns correctly IF I have ALL four strings filled. However, if one of those strings is empty, the list returned is empty. Basically, I need it to return a list even if 1 or more or even ALL of the strings are empty.

```
private List<Search> FilterSearchResults(List<Search> results)
    {
        string _dataType = cmbISDataType.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string _medium = cmbISMedium.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string _pStatus = cmbISPStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string _rStatus= cmbISRStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();

        return results
            .Where(a => a.Data_Type == _dataType && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_dataType))
            .Where(b => b.Medium == _medium && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_medium))
            .Where(c => c.PStat== _pStatus && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_pStatus ))
            .Where(d => d.RStatus== _rStatus && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_rStatus))
            .ToList();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be in the list if all strings are empty? if two of them are empty and two are not?

Comment: FYI, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188780/linq-styling-chaining-where-clause-vs-and-operator for a discussion as to whether chaining `Where` clauses or simply using `&&` is better.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Id like it to return the same results back if all strings are empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than checking whether or not the value is null in every single iteration of the loop, only perform the check when the string is not null:

```
private List<Search> FilterSearchResults(List<Search> results)
{
    string _dataType = cmbISDataType.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string _medium = cmbISMedium.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string _pStatus = cmbISPStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string _rStatus = cmbISRStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();

    IEnumerable<Search> query = results;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_dataType))
        query = query.Where(a => a.Data_Type == _dataType);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_medium))
        query = query.Where(b => b.Medium == _medium);
    if( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_pStatus))
        query = query.Where(c => c.PStat == _pStatus);
    if( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_rStatus))
        query = query.Where(d => d.RStatus == _rStatus);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your current condition specifies that any of the strings can't be null or empty which is why the list is being returned as empty. A where clause in Linq works by returning any object in the collection that satisfies the specified condition. If you were to specify the condition as simply:

```
results.Where(true);
```

All objects would be returned.

Using an OR instead of an AND for the is null or empty check will return any object in the list that evaluates true for either of conditions. Therefore if the filter string is empty all objects will be returned, otherwise only the objects which meet the other conditions will be returned.

Update your filters to:

```
return results
            .Where(a => a.Data_Type == _dataType || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_dataType))
            .Where(b => b.Medium == _medium || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_medium))
            .Where(c => c.PStat== _pStatus || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_pStatus ))
            .Where(d => d.RStatus== _rStatus || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_rStatus))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This works just fine, however I took @Servy 's response as it's a bit more efficient and only performs a check if string is not empty. Cheers.