# How to apply multiple optional filters in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable, custom-model-binder

I have a page where user can select any number of search filters to apply search

[image]

When user clicks on search, these parameters are passed to my `GetIndicatorData` method to perform the query. However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my code

```
public static List<tblindicators_data_custom> GetIndicatorsData(string status, int service_id, int operator_id, string year, string frequency)
{


    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(year + "-01-01");
    int[] numbers = status.Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray();
    var ict = new ICT_indicatorsEntities();
    var result = from ind in ict.tblindicators_data
                 join ser in ict.tblservices on ind.service_id equals ser.Id
                 join oper in ict.tbloperators on ind.operator_id equals oper.Id
                 where numbers.Contains(ind.status) && (ind.date_added.Year == date.Year) 
                 select new
                 {
                     ind.Id,
                     ind.service_id,
                     ind.survey_id,
                     ind.operator_id,
                     ind.type,
                     ind.date_added,
                     ind.quater_start,
                     ind.quater_end,
                     ind.status,
                     ind.month,
                     service = ser.name,
                     operator_name = oper.name
                 };

    List<tblindicators_data_custom> data = new List<tblindicators_data_custom>();
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        tblindicators_data_custom row = new tblindicators_data_custom();
        row.Id = item.Id;
        row.survey_id = item.survey_id;
        row.service_id = item.service_id;
        row.service_name = item.service;
        row.operator_id = item.operator_id;
        row.operator_name = item.operator_name;
        row.date_added = item.date_added;
        row.quater_start = item.quater_start;
        row.type = item.type;
        row.quater_end = item.quater_end;
        row.month = item.month == null? DateTime.Now:item.month;
        row.status = item.status;
        data.Add(row);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: One thing I usually do with search forms with optional search parameters is this: `&& (status == "" || ind.status == status) && (service_id==0 || ind.service_id == service_id)`

Comment: @bradbury9 this will not work , filters are based on if else condition , the way you mentioned it will not work.

Comment: Have you given it a try? The code I put is an if-else. If  `status == "" || ind.status == status` means 'if status variable is set, check if the value is the variable one, else retrieve the record'

Comment: @bradbury9 yes i tried it but not wokring if i set status or any value to 0 it will compare and results will be wrong.. one thing more we can't add if , else inside query. it shows syntax error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple filter LINQ search C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820343/multiple-filter-linq-search-c-sharp)

Comment: @Lucifer not its not duplicate of above example , because they are using linq and i am using iquerable

Comment: IQueryable is **not** incompatible with linq.  Check [this link](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-linq-to-sql-2-iqueryable-lt-t-gt) or this related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578778/using-iqueryable-with-linq)

Comment: @bradbury9 ok got it, can you suggest me or tell me edits in my query as per my needs.